# Showing HTML elements based on PHP value

Tags: php, html

The following code is not working, I was getting a white screen with it. Not sure what is wrong. Also, I wasn't sure if it would be better to pass $member_info to javascript and iterate through the html with jQuery?

**PHP:**

```
foreach($team_member as $member)
{
  $is_leader= false;
  if(naked_id($member->id) == naked_id($leader->id)){
     $is_leader = true;
  } 

  unset($member_data);
  $member_data->id =   $member->id;
  $member_data->leader = $is_leader;

  $member_info[] = $member_data;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<?php foreach($member_info as $member) : ?>

    <?php if ( $member->leader == true ) : ?>

        <span id="team-leader">Team Leader</span>

    <?php else : ?>

        <span id="team-leader" style="display:none;">Team Leader</span>

    <?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: display errors on ? error reporting set to E_ALL ?

Answer (score 2):

You need a colon after the foreach (in the HTML snippet you've given). As per the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) -

> In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the
>   opening brace to a colon (:)

It would then become :

```
<?php foreach($member_info as $member) : ?>
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks for pointing that out. Had it in my code, was a stupid mistake while transcribing the code here, thanks!